# Transparent ssh connection forwarding to a docker container

Tags: docker, ssh, forwarding, authorized-keys

I want to have a server to transparently forward an incoming ssh connection from a client to a docker container. This should include scp, git transport and so forth. This must work with keys, passwords are deactivated. The user should not see the server. *Update: Yes, this really means that the user shall be unaware that there is a server. The configuration must take place entirely on the server!*

```
client -----> server -----> container  (actual connection)
client -------------------> container  (what the user should see)
```

So, what is given is this:

```
user@client$ ssh user@server
user@server$ ssh -p 42 user@localhost
user@container$
```

But what I want is this:

```
user@client$ ssh user@server
user@container$
```

I tried using the `command="ssh -p 42 user@localhost"` syntax in the `authorized_keys` files, which kinda works, only that in the second ssh connection the user has to enter their password as the authentication is not passed (the `server` doesn't has the private key of `user`).
Further this approach doesn't work with `scp` even if one enters a password.

I also heard about the `tunnel=` command, but I don't know how to set that up (and the manpage is less than helpful).

I am using OpenSSH 7.5p1 on Arch.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host server-container
  ProxyCommand ssh server -W localhost:42
```

Then simply do:

```
ssh server-container
```

---

As long as your usernames are consistent. If not, you can specify them as this:

```
Host server-container
  ProxyCommand ssh server-user@server -W localhost:42
```

Then simply do:

```
ssh container-user@server-container
```

---

Just as a bonus, you can avoid to use ssh to enter into the container using `docker exec`. Like this:

```
ssh -t server docker exec -it <container-id> bash
```

Comment: As I said, it must be configured serverside. The client is not malicious, but ... how shall I put it ... not sufficiently competent.

Comment: Iptables? Or ssh agent?

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I came up with now. I'm a bit unhappy with the second key, as it's public part will be visible in the `container`'s `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` which very slightly breaks transparency, but other than that all other things seem to work.

```
user@server$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
command="ssh  -q -p 42 user@localhost -- \"$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND\"",no-X11-forwarding ssh-rsa <KEYSTRING_1>
user@server$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
<KEYSTRING_2>
user@container$ cat .ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-rsa <KEYSTRING_2>
```

The `client` authorises against `server` with their private key. Then the server jumps to the `container` with a dedicated key that is only there for that particular auth. I'm a bit worried that you can break out of `command=` by injecting some commands, but so far I found no permutation that allows to break out.
Due to passing `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`, you can even do `scp` and `ssh-copy-id` and so forth.

Note: To disallow `ssh-copy-id`, which I want for other reasons, simply make `authorized_keys` non-writeable for `user` inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be 2 parts:

- Direct access to the container
- Authentication with the server

### Direct Access to Container

You could bypass the SSH connection to the container altogether but still *act* like SSH is connecting to the container (use the username and the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file from the container as well as have a silent "redirect" into the container with no direct access to the server). I'm going to assume that the user exists on both the server and in the container and that the usernames match. We'll call the user `ssh_username` here.

On the server, you would `docker exec` a shell in the container (not SSHing into the container). Set the shell for `ssh_username` on the sever to be something like:

`/usr/local/bin/docker-shell`:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/docker exec -it -u ${USER} --env SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND="${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" container_name sh "${@}"
```

To create this you would do:

```bash
cat <<"EOF" | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/docker-shell > /dev/null
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/docker exec -it -u ${USER} --env SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND="${SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND}" container_name sh "${@}"
EOF
sudo chmod a+rx /usr/local/bin/docker-shell
```

### Server Authentication

Since we aren't using passwords and we don't want the users to have a shell on the server, we can create the users like this:

```bash
useradd -M -s /usr/local/bin/docker-shell -N -g nogroup ssh_username
mkdir /home/ssh_username
chown ssh_username /home/ssh_username
```

(using `-M` to prevent default files being created in home directory, `-N` to prevent matching group creation)

Now, you'll need to have that `ssh_username` auth to the server, not the container, but we don't want to have to maintain the `authorized_keys` files in both places. We'll use SSH's `AuthorizedKeysCommand` to fetch them from the Docker container.

Here is how you would configure the `AuthorizedKeysCommand` on the server. Edit the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file to add:

```
Match User ssh_username
  AuthorizedKeysCommandUser some_server_user_with_docker_access
  AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/docker exec -i cat /home/ssh_username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

`some_server_user_with_docker_access` would be replaced with a user that is in the `docker` groups on `server` because this user is going to need to be able to run `docker exec` on the server. This could also be the `ssh_username` but then you would need to add that user to the `docker` group, and you may not want to do that.